# Space Invaders killing multiple enemies

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am making a Space Invaders old classic game and here is my problem

Actually I want to kill enemies but when luckily hitting original one then only the code is working.
Please help.

I have tried all the things and here is my final code after making all the efforts.

I was thinking to try of making ID's for each enemy:

```
import pygame
import random
import math

# Initialise
pygame.init()

# Title & Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load("si.ico")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Background
background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")

# Player
playerimg = pygame.image.load("sip.png")
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

# Enemy

enemyimg = []
enemyY = []
enemyX = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
n_e = 10
for i in range(n_e):
    enemyimg.append(pygame.image.load("sie.ico"))
    # clearimg = pygame.image.load("clear.png")
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 736))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))

    enemyX_change.append(2)
    enemyY_change.append(40)

# Bullet
bulletimg = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
bulletX = 370
bulletY = 481
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 10
bullet_state = "ready"


# Fuctions

def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyimg[i], (x, y))


# def cleanenemy(x, y):
# screen.blit(clearimg, (x, y))


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))


def fire(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletimg, (x + 16, y + 10))


def collission_chk(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = int(math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX[i] - bulletX, 2) + (math.pow(enemyY[i] - bulletY, 2))))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# Game Loop
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 5

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -5

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bulletX = playerX
                fire(playerX, bulletY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            playerX_change = 0

    playerX += playerX_change
    if playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736
    elif playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0

    collission = collission_chk(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY)

    for i in range(n_e):

        if collission:
            bulletY = playerY
            # screen.blit(clearimg, (enemyX, enemyY))
            bullet_state = "ready"
            enemyX[i] = 7000
            enemyY[i] = 7000

        else:
            enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] >= 736:
            enemyX_change[i] = -2
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] <= 0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 2
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

    if bulletY <= 0:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state == "fire":
        fire(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

    player(playerX, playerY)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: could you please elabourate your problem like what does "Actually I want to kill enemies but when luckily hitting original one then only the code is working plz help" mean plz elaborate so I can help as I also made the same game and it works perfectly fine

Comment: see, I have multiple enemies on the screen and when the bullet is hitting one of them nothing happens but i remember that i added a code for it that when a bullet hits the enemy the enemy co-ordinates changes to 7000

Comment: actually i tried the same code from this video

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfWpgLFMI7w&t=1756s

Comment: LOL even i did from that video only.....wait let me compare your code with my code

Comment: did you got it??

Comment: bro I am not a professional debugger is it fine if I give you my code wit images and everything ?? and you can compare both

Comment: no problem i am also a begginer i will try :)

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/y1q2t9o27uqgohn/space_invador.zip/file here are my files with images and sounds hope it helps you

Comment: actually the issues tab and of course your file helped me solving my problem Thank You So much for your help :)

Comment: Ohh ggreat your problem got solved.BTW where was the problem??!